# IDispatch structures FUNCDESC and ELEMDESC

Tags: automation

I'm trying to hardcode the offsets and size in bytes of the FUNCDESC stucture (Windows, 32 bits) and I'm having trouble understanding whether these offsets are correct or not:

```
0  MEMBERID   memid;
4  SCODE      *lprgscode;
8  ELEMDESC  *lprgelemdescParam;
12  FUNCKIND   funckind;
16  INVOKEKIND invkind;
20  CALLCONV   callconv;
24  SHORT      cParams;
26  SHORT      cParamsOpt;
28  SHORT      oVft;
30  SHORT      cScodes;
32  ELEMDESC   elemdescFunc;
48  WORD       wFuncFlags;
```

According to this layout ELEMDESC would take 16 bytes and FUNCDESC 50. Is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to confirm the layout and size of the structures. And yes, `ELEMDESC` is 16 bytes long and `FUNCDESC` 50. All offsets are correct too.